# Opening python idle in Notepad++ results in error

Tags: python, notepad++

I used this code in f5 to run python code

```
C:\Python34\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat -r "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

this works fine when running native python commands and code
yet when I use code from other modules such as pygame it does not run
I made a pygame and on idle it runs well yet when trying to lanuch from notepad++ it gives and error that it can open a png file yet on idle it runs fine. Any ideas on what can be wrong?

Comment: Use the full path to the png file in your application, and not a relative path.

Comment: how can i mention both the idle and the png in the same command also there is more than one png file that I call in my code